# Lambda Logs To show in Application Interface with search option

Tags: aws-lambda

We are developing an application in which we are using serverless architecture. Here each and every action invokes a lambda function the result of which is logged in to cloudwatch.
Now we have a requirement that the logs need to be available in the application and the data should be able to be filtered using different options along with custom search options.
We are looking for a cost effection AWS solutions.

Comment: Hi Akhil. Your question is far too broad for Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a consulting website designing a complete solution for you for _free_. The Stackoverflow community is here to help you fix specific problems with the code _you_ write. Maybe you should detail which solutions you are considering at the moment and ask for feedback on those options _you_ provide.

Comment: So you want to show your _internal_ logs of your Lambda functions inside your application? Why? For the admins/support ppl. of your application? Anyways, instead of re-implementing a solution, you could also just give the relevant users access to CloudWatch and let them use e.g. CloudWatch Insights for your Lambda logs -> there you can search/filter/aggregate/whatever you like, and it's cost efficient.